# Acumatica using images in replace of CheckBox

Tags: acumatica

I want to be able to click on the rendered button and have the new value save.

In customization Project there are values for images for when the checkbox is pushed.

[image]

Currently, the Checkbox rendered as a button correctly displays the correct image for the value in the project but when the button is clicked and the user saves the project the value and button reverts to its original state.

GIF: http://g.recordit.co/vbe99tL7Q7.gif

If I remove the Render Style, the checkbox works normally in the project without displaying any images.

Is there something im missing in Customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working with AutoCallBack defined for checkBox. AutoCallBack is calling an action from BLC every time a user clicks on the button representing checkbox.

**Checkbox definition in Aspx:**

```
<px:PXCheckBox runat="server" ID="chkUsrBoolField" CallbackUpdatable="True" DataField="UsrBoolField" RenderStyle="Button" AlignLeft="True" >
    <AutoCallBack Command="CheckFlag" Target="ds" />
    <UncheckImages Normal="main@Fail" />
    <CheckImages Normal="main@Success" />
</px:PXCheckBox>
```

**PMProject DAC and ProjectEntryExt BLC extensions:**

```
public class PMProjectExt : PXCacheExtension<PMProject>
{
    public abstract class usrBoolField : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBBool]
    public bool? UsrBoolField { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
{
    public PXAction<PMProject> CheckFlag;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(Visible = false)]
    protected void checkFlag()
    {
        var proj = Base.Project.Current;
        proj.GetExtension<PMProjectExt>().UsrBoolField = 
            !proj.GetExtension<PMProjectExt>().UsrBoolField.GetValueOrDefault();
        Base.Project.Update(proj);
    }
}
```